# ALTER SYSTEM is not executing in jruby

Tags: oracle, plsql, jruby

I am trying to execute plsql block in which I have ALTER USER and then ALTER SYSTEM statements one after other. ALTER USER is executing but ALTER SYSTEM is not.

My code does the following:
1. Connects to the database using jdbc driver.
2. Changes the login user of a particular user (here I am using ALTER USER statement).
3. Kills the session of that particular user before dropping it (here I use ALTER SYSTEM statement which is not running).

Below is the code fragment which is not running for me.

```
users = ['ABC', 'XYZ']

$users.each do|x|
          if( is_usr?("#{x}") )
               puts "Working on #{x}"

               stmt = <<-EOF
                         DECLARE
                                   id NUMber(10);
                                     s_num NUMBER(10);
                                     CURSOR cur IS
                                     SELECT sid, serial#
                                     FROM v$session WHERE username like ('#{x}');

                         BEGIN
                                    OPEN cur;
                                    LOOP
                                        FETCH cur INTO id, s_num;
                                        dbms_output.put_line(id||' '||s_num);
                                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER #{x} IDENTIFIED BY dummypass';
                                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ''' ||id|| ',' ||s_num||'''';
                                        EXIT when sess_cur%notfound;
                                    END LOOP;
                                   CLOSE cur;
                               END;
                      EOF

                 puts "#{stmt}"
                 plsql = @conn.create_statement
                 plsql.execute_update(stmt)

                 else
                      puts "#{x} does not exist"
                 end
end
```

Output looks like this:

```
Working on ABC

                            DECLARE
                                                                id NUMber(10);
                                                                s_num NUMBER(10);
                                                                CURSOR cur IS
                                                                        SELECT sid, serial#
                                                                        FROM v$session WHERE username like ('ABC');

                                                        BEGIN
                                                                OPEN cur;
                                                                LOOP
                                                                        FETCH cur INTO id, s_num;
                                                                        dbms_output.put_line(id||' '||s_num);
                                                                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ABC IDENTIFIED BY dummypass';
                                                                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ''' ||id|| ',' ||s_num||'''';
                                                                        EXIT when sess_cur%notfound;
                                                                END LOOP;
                                                                CLOSE cur;
                                                        END;

Working on XYZ
                                                       DECLARE
                                                                id NUMber(10);
                                                                s_num NUMBER(10);
                                                                CURSOR cur IS
                                                                        SELECT sid, serial#
                                                                        FROM v$session WHERE username like ('XYZ');

                                                        BEGIN
                                                                OPEN cur;
                                                                LOOP
                                                                        FETCH cur INTO id, s_num;
                                                                        dbms_output.put_line(id||' '||s_num);
                                                                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER XYZ IDENTIFIED BY dummypass';
                                                                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ''' ||id|| ',' ||s_num||'''';
                                                                        EXIT when sess_cur%notfound;
                                                                END LOOP;
                                                                CLOSE cur;
                                                        END;
```

Observation after running this script:
1. I am able to login to db as ABC and XYZ with 'dummypass' as password. Hence I know that ALTER USER statement has been run successfully.
2. I still see all the same session ids and serial#s for 'ABC' and 'XYZ'. Hence I know that ALTER SYSTEM statement did not run.

I am struggling in fixing this one since past 3-days. Please help me in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work outside of JRuby?

Comment: Yes, I ran it as a separate plsql block and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION` does not instantly get rid of the session.  It only marks it for being killed.  Normally a background process will get rid of it in a minute.  If there are many uncommitted changes it can take a very long time to rollback everything.

There is no way to speed up the process.  The best you can do it ignore those sessions with a predicate like `where v$session.status <> 'KILLED'`.

Comment: I updated the`ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION` by adding the where clause to check the status. This time I am getting the following SQL error: `NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00026: missing or invalid session ID
ORA-06512: at line 15`. I looked at the status of each user and it was marked as "KILLED". How can I get over this problem?

Comment: Add the condition to the cursor instead of the `ALTER`.

Comment: I tried to add the following: `CURSOR sess_cur IS                                                                  IF(v$session.status <> 'KILLED') THEN SELECT sid, serial#                                       FROM v$session WHERE username like ('ABC'); END IF;` but it gave the following error: `NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 5, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:  ( select <a SQL statement>`. is there a syntax problem with the cursor condition?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT sid, serial# FROM v$session WHERE username like ('ABC') and status <> 'KILLED'`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it was giving the following error message: `NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00026: missing or invalid session ID ORA-06512: at line 15`. I checked the status of user before running the script and it was `INACTIVE`. After running the script, status was `KILLED`. My final goal is to drop the particular user after killing all the sessions. But I am stuck at killing session now.